# Road Closures not visible on Mapbox Traffic Layer

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to implement road closures in the traffic layer of our map but I am not able to verify it as I cannot see any change w.r.t road closure on the map.

I took reference from this link https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-traffic-v1/#road-closures

Please find this JS fiddle link.. I had used the closed class earlier but was not able to see any change so reverted the code to initial state.

[Mapbox traffic layer][1]

[1]: https:// jsfiddle.net/navv_navi/Lt3hmawd/3/